# Wordpress Ultimate Member adding account fields placeholders instead of labels

Tags: wordpress, label, field

Does anyone know how to add placeholders values to the existing Ultimate member account fields like "First name", "Password", "Company" etc.? Basically for all the account fields.
I want to style the fields by removing the labels and keeping only the placeholders..

Answer (score 0):

Since no one answered this is all that I've managed to achieve, maybe it serves anyone else stuck in this matter:

```
    add_filter( 'um_first_name_form_edit_field', 'my_form_edit_field', 10, 2 );
    function my_form_edit_field( $output, $mode ) {
    
      $fields = UM()->builtin()->get_specific_fields( 'first_name' );
      foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
       
        $fields['first_name']['placeholder'] = $fields['first_name']['title'];
        $field_value = get_user_meta(um_user('ID'), $key, true) ? : '';
    
        $output = '<div class="um-field um-field-'.$key.'" data-key="'.$key.'">
        <div class="um-field-label">
        <label for="'.$key.'">'.$fields['first_name']['title'].'</label>
        <div class="um-clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="um-field-area">
        <input class="um-form-field valid "
        type="text" name="'.$key.'"
        id="'.$key.'" value="'.$field_value.'"
        placeholder="'.$fields['first_name']['title'].'"
        data-validate="" data-key="'.$key.'">
        </div>
        </div>';
    
        //echo $output;
      }
    
    
      return $output;
    }
```

I still need a way to do this for all the fields not only for a specific one like this.